# collating common values and adding integers in a hash

Tags: perl

I'm writing a script that parses a metric port and outputs metric names and values to a hash, then reads the hash and passes metric names and values to gmetric. However, since I have multiple instances of the same process running, I have duplicate names in one field of the hash:

```
[MacOSX_Leopard,2
 Win32_Windows,5
 MacOSX,2
 Win32_Windows,5]
```

What I would like to do is be able to collate and add up these values into one total for each metric involved. How/What is the best way to do this in perl?

Comment: Perl hashes cannot have duplicate keys, so when you say "I have duplicate names in one field of the hash" I think you mean something else. Can you put the question in programming terms as to where specifically you have this data of OS names and values stored?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you are meaning to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$value{"MacOSX_Leopard"} += 5;
$value{"MacOSX_Leopard"} += 3;
$value{"MacOSX"} += 3;
$value{"Windows"} += 2;

foreach $key (keys %value) {
   print "$key\t",$value{$key},"\n";
}
```

Result:

```
MacOSX  3
Windows 2
MacOSX_Leopard  8
```